# what can I use for the database part in flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, dart, flutter

am trying to create a simple login system with flutter but I don't know the options available (that I can use) for the backend can I use sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use SQLITE.

Get started with the [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) plugin.

Alternatively, you can use the [flutter_sqlcipher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sqlcipher) or [firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) plugins.

if you want to use Firebase take a look at this:

- [iOS](https://youtu.be/3nFIMej3Tvw)
- [Android](https://youtu.be/t_SgDznY99k)